# Flat, weak finish to my homebrew. Sign of it being young?

Tags: flavor, aging

I bottled my homebrew a week ago - TrueBrew Bavarian Hefeweizen.  Yesterday I popped a bottle to make sure it was carbonating, and for a sneak preview.  I was pleasantly surprised with the aroma and flavor up front, but the finish was weak and left something to be desired.

Just curious (since I have nothing but time on my hands to worry), is it possible this is just because I only bottled a week ago, and will get better with age?  Or perhaps could I have done something better\different for my batch.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1** - I got a few comments all seeming to indicate that the beer was "flat".  I shouldn't have used that term at all in the title (sorry), the beer wasn't "flat", I was talking about the flavor of the beer itself, the taste was just bland.  A nice aroma and flavor up front, and a nice mouth feel (for only one week into conditioning), but the finish on the palate was.. well.. perhaps like a light flat beer.  It's hard to explain, send me your address and I'll send a bottle lol.

Comment: Was it flat after a week?  What priming sugar did you use?  By "weak finish", do you mean low alcohol?

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I updated my post to address your comment in Edit 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a sign of the age of the beer, and it won't hurt to give it some more time to see if it improves. Not having tasted it, I suspect that it might not.

In general I wouldn't think of aging as improving a taste I would describe as "weak" or "flat" though. Aging tends to smooth out the flavors and allow different notes to blend and become more cohesive. If there's an aspect to the taste that it's lacking it probably won't appear with age, but if there's a part that you want to taste more of that might happen.

BJCP describes hefeweizen as:

> Flavor: Low to moderately strong banana and clove flavor. The balance and intensity of the phenol and ester components can vary but the best examples are reasonably balanced and fairly prominent. Optionally, a very light to moderate vanilla character and/or low bubblegum notes can accentuate the banana flavor, sweetness and roundness; neither should be dominant if present. The soft, somewhat bready or grainy flavor of wheat is complementary, as is a slightly sweet Pils malt character. Hop flavor is very low to none, and hop bitterness is very low to moderately low. A tart, citrusy character from yeast and high carbonation is often present. Well rounded, flavorful palate with a relatively dry finish. No diacetyl or DMS.

Most of which I wouldn't associate with age. On the other hand, if you say the aroma is good, then the flavor might get better. I wouldn't expect it to get worse with a little more time, but I don't think the style will do well with a lot of aging. Try one next week, and the following weeks for a month maybe two. If you still don't like where it's going then it's probably as good as it's going to get. I've been able to cook pretty well with beers that weren't any good to drink.

Comment: Thanks @BBS, please read my post, edit 1.  The beer itself wasn't flat, this was more a question on the flavor.. not sure if that alter's your answer at all.  thx!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ewitkows. I updated my answer, and offered some extra thoughts.